# Как отталкиваться от элемента в xml android

Tags: android, xml

Мне нужно оттолкнуться от конкретного элемента как это сделать в xml?

У меня есть `EditText` и есть кнопка, мне нужно чтобы `EditText` отталкивался от кнопки на нужное мне количество `dp`.

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень расплывчатый. Пожалуйста, предоставьте ваш образец XML и объясните, что вам нужно с ним делать.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky К сожалению не могу, но если конкретнее у меня есть EditText и есть кнопка, мне нужно чтобы EditText отталкивался от кнопки на нужное мне количество dp

Comment: Вам нужен margin. А также связать вьюхи. Это делается по разному, в зависимости от используемого для вьюх контейнера

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы оттолкнуться от какого-то элемента, вам нужно знать его координаты. Дальше вы прописываете анимацию:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true" android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

и в активности например в onCreate() вызываете данную анимацию:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val bounceAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce_animation)

    val textViewToBounce = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewToBounce)
    textViewToBounce.setOnClickListener {
        textViewToBounce.startAnimation(bounceAnimation)
    }
}
```

Вот [статья](https://medium.com/@saishaddai/how-to-bounce-a-view-in-android-cee4aad83bce) по данному вопросу. Для того чтобы получить координаты элемента от которого вы хотите отталкиваться, можно использовать [данный](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])) способ:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
myView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

Так же [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937748/make-bounce-animation) вопрос подобный вашему.

### UPDATE

Если под оттолкнуться вы подразумеваете отступ между полем для  ввода и кнопкой, то не помешал бы ваш xml)) Есть два вида отступов: внутренние и наружные. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Внутренние отступы влияют на содержимое контейнера `view` и могут двигать это содержимое внутри этого контейнера. Наружные отступы влияют на расположение view в родительском. Наружные отступы это `margin` а внутренние `padding`. То что вы спрашиваете это вероятнее всего `margin`. Так как сторон у прямоугольного/квадратного элемента 4, то и `margin` есть 4 варианта:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="dp"
android:layout_marginRight="dp"
android:layout_marginTop="dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="dp"
```

в кавычках указывается на сколько `dp` элемент должен отодвинуться от чего-либо. Например отступ сверху на `10dp` можно установить так:

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Вот есть интересные уроки и статьи по вопросу установки отступов: [1](https://metanit.com/java/android/3.10.php), [2](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/), [3](https://www.studytonight.com/android/margin-vs-padding). [Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).

Comment: Я не добавил деталей и по этому вы меня не так поняли, но спасибо за развернутый ответ, выше в комментариях описал ситуацию

Comment: Видимо под "оттолкнуться" человек понимает просто сделать отступ между виджетами

Comment: @pavlofff, я уже  понял)) обновил немного ответ :)